# solution of linear equation

Tags: optimization

I have the following optimization problem:
       \begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
\underset{x}{\text{min}}
{\sum_{i=1}^{k}} w_{i}x
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Is the solution x = 0? Here $w_{i}$ is given. Both $w_{i}$ and x are scalars.

Comment: No, there is no minimum.

Comment: Hint, select $x_i = -t w_i$ and see what happens when you let $t$ tend to $\infty$